# How can I replace a globally defined repository variable in GitHub from within a GitHub Action?

Tags: environment-variables, github-actions, repository, workflow

I have defined a GitHub repository variable via `Settings -> Secrets and variables -> Actions --> Tab Variables -> Repository Variable's` presetting with a start/default value. This variable holds the last commit SHA.

How can I replace this variable's value in a GitHub workflow (or job respectively) with the new SHA after a new commit so that the new value is available in the next run?

The reason to do this is that I have a repository containing separated sources for frontend and backend.
I am using GitHub Actions to trigger the build, creating an image, put it into a registry, ...

When committing/pushing into the repo I am already able to recognize if changes where made in FE, BE, both or none.

If, for instance, changes where only made in BE, I only want to do the whole stuff for BE but not for the FE and update the repository variable named VERSION_BE with the SHA of the last (BE) commit.
For the FE part I don't want to execute all the steps. Instead, I want to use the FE image with the SHA stored in the repository variable VERSION_FE during the last build.
When creating/tagging the newly created image I simply want to read out the (updated) repository variables VERSION_BE and VERSION_FE.

Comment: Why does it need to be stored, you already get access to the commit sha in the contexts exposed to the workflow.

Comment: I want it to be stored because in the repo there are sources for BE/FE and I want to build only the part win which changes where made. The different SHA's shall be used for tagging the resulting image.

Comment: There's an [API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/variables?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-a-repository-variable) that lets you update repo variables, but I'm pretty sure there are easier ways such as `git log <directory>` and extracting the hash from there instead of relying on some process to update the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [github CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows) and run it from workflow.

You should use [gh variable set](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_variable_set)

```yaml
on: 
    workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
            gh variable list
            gh variable set TEST_VAR --body "Set from workflow"
            gh variable list
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FULL_PAT }}
```

[image]

This issue

> 'failed to set variable "VERSION_BE": HTTP 403: Resource not accessible by integration

is related to not enough permissions in token you used. I had the same and switched to Personal Token with full access.

I tried adding permission via `permisions: write-all` field but I got the same result.

Comment: Should it be secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN or vars.GITHUB_TOKEN? Why do I have to use GITHUB_TOKEN at all??

Comment: Results in: line 2: gh: command not found

Comment: What runners do you use? `GitHub CLI is preinstalled on all GitHub-hosted runners. For each step that uses GitHub CLI, you must set an environment variable called GITHUB_TOKEN to a token with the required scopes.`

Comment: I fixed the missing gh command. The variable VERSION_BE is already defined.
Now, I get: failed to set variable "VERSION_BE": HTTP 404: Not Found (https://api.github.com/repositories/671533978/environments/repository/variables)

Comment: Could you try first list all your variables?

Comment: If I do 'gh variable list' in the console I see the defined variables and I can edit them with 'gh variable set...' but using 'gh variable set VERSION_BE --body "${{ env.SHORT_SHA }}"' in the workflow file results in the HTTP 404.

Comment: run: |
        echo "VERSION_BE is ${{ vars.VERSION_BE }}"
        gh variable set VERSION_BE --body "${{ env.SHORT_SHA }}"
        echo "VERSION_BE is now ${{ vars.VERSION_BE }}"
      env:
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
The first echo command displays the current value of the variable.

Comment: Previosuly I used: gh variable set VERSION_BE --env repository --body "${{ env.SHORT_SHA }}"
Then I removed the '--env repository' part. Now getting: 'failed to set variable "VERSION_BE": HTTP 403: Resource not accessible by integration'

Comment: I solely have the gh step: gh variable set VERSION_BE --body "xxx"

Comment: Check also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76012627/2347999

Comment: I also tried with the same effect. I just created PAT token with full access (probably it could be narrowed). and saved is as secret `FULL_PAT`

Comment: Weird: Although I have '      env:
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FULL_PAT }}' in my action I get 
'gh: To use GitHub CLI in a GitHub Actions workflow, set the GH_TOKEN environment variable. Example:
  env:
    GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}'

Comment: But did you save you PAT in secrets?

Comment: Just saw that. Must figure out how to do ...

Comment: Here you have docs for this https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

Comment: Just added a fine grained PAT defining repository variable write permission. Error message still occurs. (Named it GH CLI PAT --> accessing as GH_CLI_PAT).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255126/discussion-between-krzysztof-madej-and-du-it).